# Leetcode 494 Brute force recursive solution works with a variable as a attribute but doesn't work when I pass it as parameter

Tags: java, recursion, parameters, scope, pass-by-value

I have attached the solution here. 1st one works but the second doesn't. The only change is I have moved the result variable as an attribute with global scope to a parameter in the helper function.

```
class Solution {
    int result = 0;
    
    public int findTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S) {
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return result;
        helper(nums, S, 0, 0);
        return result;
    }
    
    public void helper(int[] nums, int target, int pos, long eval){
        if (pos == nums.length) {
            if (target == eval) result++;
            return;
        }
        helper(nums, target, pos + 1, eval + nums[pos]);
        helper(nums, target, pos + 1, eval - nums[pos]);
    }
}
```

```
class Solution {
    
    public int findTargetSumWays(int[] nums, int S) {
        int result = 0;
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return result;
        helper(nums, S, 0, 0, result);
        return result;
    }
    
    public void helper(int[] nums, int target, int pos, long eval, int result){
        if (pos == nums.length) {
            if (target == eval) result++;
            return;
        }
        helper(nums, target, pos + 1, eval + nums[pos], result);
        helper(nums, target, pos + 1, eval - nums[pos], result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitives (like int in your case) are handed by value in Java. In your first solution, it's a class attribute. In the second solution, the value is declared in findTargetSumWays() and its value is modified in helper(). This cannot work the way you implement it

Instead of :

```java
int i=0;
modifyValue(i);
```

It should be :

```java
int i=0;
i = modifyValue(i);
```

Comment: Quick follow up: That means attributes or class fields are passed as reference as in first solution where the attribute result gets updated?